# Using my own key in an AES encryption algorithm implementation

Tags: encryption, aes, java

I have the following code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESHelper {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }
}
```

and the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String normalText = "VIJAY";
        String normalTextEnc;

        try{
            normalTextEnc = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, normalText);
            String normalTextDec = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, normalTextEnc);
            TextView txe = new TextView(this);
            txe.setTextSize(14);
            txe.setText("Normal Text ::" + normalText + " \n Encrypted Value :: " + normalTextEnc + " \n Decrypted value :: " + normalTextDec);
            setContentView(txe);
        }catch(Exception e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use my own key? 
What is the use of a rawKey?

Comment: I think you're having a programming problem: *"How can I make my code do <this>?"*. This may be better suited at StackOverflow as we're not experts at programming (well not all of us) but rather at the math and secure implementation and usage of crypto rather than the programming of such stuff. But you made it rather tricky to 100% judge whether this should be migrated because you also ask about the use of rawkey (although this may be a programming question as well).

Comment: BTW: I think rawKey is the AES key being fed into the encryption function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually had doubts about whether I should post it here or in SO. 
Last time I asked there about encryption implementation though, they told me to ask it here.

 Regarding your answer, I'm not sure it works.
I tried doing:
`SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");`
while raw is actually the byte[] of my own key. Basically I skipped the getRawKey functions. 
And now nothing happens when I try to encrypt/decrypt.

What if I change the seedValue to my key ? Can the seed function as the key ? Or I misunderstood the whole thing?

Comment: I think the rawkey is *actually* the secret key used by AES (the 128/192/256 bit key) and SecretKeySpec specifies some other properties of the secret keys. Indeed the secret key (=rawKey) for AES is derived from SeedValue using the "SHA1PRNG". So you can control the key using the seed.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I use the rawkey as the key , nothing happens. I press the encrypt button and I have no output whatsoever.

Comment: Well, you have two functions at your disposal: One function that actually encrypts data (accepting the byte[] arguments) and one that just wraps this functionality for strings. The second one only accepts a seed and not the actual key. You'd have to call the first function (taking the byte[]) for actually encrypting your data using the passed key (and not some derivative). And please tell me this is just a hobby / research project because you actually use ECB, which is pretty bad.

Comment: Well I have a php example of Rijdael-256 which I need to convert to an Android app.  The php example uses ECB. But I think I can use something else, it's not currently the issue. (By the way, what would you recommend instead?)

I'm trying to call the second function ,the one that actually encrypts (the one that receives byte[] as params), but as I said - nothing happens. 
It frustrates me .. I've been on it for quite some time..

Comment: As mode GCM would be best, but you'd have to supply a unique 12 byte value for each message. This may be a display problem. Can you successfully output whether "normalText==normalTextDec"?

Comment: Previously , I put in a certain string, pressed a button and I saw the encrypted string at the encrypted section. Then I put in that output I got, and pressed decrypt button and I saw the original word in the decrypted section.
So I think the display isn't the issue. Or perhaps I misunderstood what you were asking?

thank you.

Comment: If you'd change the type of normalText to byte[] and set it to some pre-defined value (like 0x1,0x2,0x3,...) and you'd feed that in. Will "normalText==NormalTextDec" hold? (without using strings at all to avoid calling the string based encryption function) You could check that by doing some if-else and outputting "it works" or "nope" whether the encryption-decryption works.

Comment: No, it turns out that it stops after the line 
`Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); `

which means that the problem is probably with the line :
`cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); `
or more likely with the line:
`SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");`
while raw is the key I give it.

Comment: The [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#SecretKeySpec%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29) would actually allow fo supplying your own secret key via `SecretKeySpec`. Did you ensure that your `raw` is actually of size 16, 24 or 32 bytes?

Comment: well I haven't made much changes to the code that I posted.. so no, I don't see where I ensure that. I'm also not really sure what you mean. What if it's not 16,24,32? Do I need to cut it?

Comment: If the raw key supplied to SecretKeySpec isn't of the correct size (16, 24 or 32 bytes) it will actually allow that but AES won't accept that and hence will fail. If it's of the wrong size you'd want to either truncate (bad idea) or use a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). Did you try with a fixed `raw` like 16x `0x00`?

Comment: yes , tried doing:
`raw = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`
just before the SecretKeySpec...
and it works.
You were right.. Ok so now, what is the easiet/shortest way to overcome this?

Comment: You'll feed the key into the encryption routine as well as plain text. Where the key comes from is the more interesting question. What are you trying to do? File encryption? Transmission channel encryption?

Answer (score 0):

That's the `getRawKey` function I've been fighting against for as long as I'm on StackOverflow. To use a password, use PBKDF2, it's build into Java. To create a random key, use a random number generator `new SecureRandom()` and `SecretKeySpec`.

If your random number generator ever does anything unexpected, e.g. generating a random number instead of acting as a deterministic PRNG your key will not be the same and you may never decrypt your ciphertext again. This actually happened after an update on Android where the default provider was replaced and the RNG differed from the one before.

Comment: What if I skip the getRawKey function altogether and just pass the byte[] raw - a certain key of my own. For example a static private String key="key";
?

Comment: The idea of a secret key is that all the bits in the key are indistinguishable from random to an attacker. So you can generate your own key by using a secure random number generator. Then you need to store this key somehow, e.g. in a `KeyStore`. If you want to store this key as text then you should convert it e.g. to hexadecimals or base 64. If you want to think up your own string you are basically using a password or phrase. In that case you need PBKDF2 to convert it into a key.

Answer (score -1):

```
    package com.example.encryption;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import java.util.Base64;

    public class AESOwnKey {
        private Cipher ecipher;
        private Cipher dcipher;

        AESOwnKey(SecretKey key) {
            try {
                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed in initialization");
            }
        }

        public byte[] encrypt(String str) {
            try {
                byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

                return Base64.getEncoder().encode(enc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed in Encryption");
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String decrypt(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);

                byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

                return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed in Decryption");
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String mykey = "1234567891234567";
                SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(mykey.getBytes(), "AES");
                AESOwnKey encrypter = new AESOwnKey(key);
                String original = "Testing encryption";
                System.out.println("Before Encryption   : " + original);
                byte[] encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(original);
                System.out.println("After Encryption   : " + encrypted);
                String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
                System.out.println("After Decryption   : " + decrypted);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, yeah let's paste a random **insecure** piece of code as answer without explanation.